# how to run batches in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I try to run schedule.bat:

```
@echo off
C:\scripts\batch1.bat
C:\scripts\batch2.bat
C:\scripts\batch3.bat
```

Where each batchx.bat is:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\otherfolder\"
echo "start batch1"
someprogram.exe parameter1
echo "batch1 end"
popd
```

(different parameters and sometimes more someprograms, so I can't do it in loop)

When I try to run schedule.bat it executes only first bat (in this example batch1

When I copied contents into one bat - it works properly, so this isn't problem with my programs - end of batch1 ends also schedule.bat...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a batch file directly invokes another batch file, execution control is transfered to the called one and does not return to the caller.

This behaviour changes if the call operation is done using the `call` command.

```
@echo off
call C:\scripts\batch1.bat
call C:\scripts\batch2.bat
call C:\scripts\batch3.bat
```

This way once the called batch file ends, the execution returns to the caller.